# Cypress auto submit on login page from beforeEach in second test

Tags: authentication, cypress, wikipedia, cypress-custom-commands

I'm working on a Cypress test for the Polish Wikipedia plugin, and I have this code in my cypress test:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (orig, path, options) => {
  return orig(`https://pl.wikipedia.org/${path}`);
});

Cypress.Commands.add('login', (pass) => {
  cy.visit('/w/index.php?title=Specjalna:Zaloguj');
  cy.get('#wpName1').type('<username>');
  cy.get('#wpPassword1').type(pass);
  cy.get('#userloginForm form').submit();
});

Cypress.Commands.add('dark_vector_wait', (pass) => {
  cy.get('.vector-menu-content-list > li:nth-child(7)', { timeout: 10000 }).should('be.visible');
});
```

And in my spec:

```js
describe('dark vector test', () => {
  beforeEach('login', () => {
    cy.login(Cypress.env('WIKI_PASSWORD'));
  });

  it('test discussion', () => {
    cy.visit('/wiki/Dyskusja_wikipedysty:<username>');
    cy.dark_vector_wait();
    cy.matchImageSnapshot('discussion');
  });

  it('testing-page page', () => {
    cy.visit('/wiki/Wikipedysta:<username>/testing-page');
    cy.dark_vector_wait();
    cy.matchImageSnapshot('testing-page');
  });
});
```

And the second test is failing because as soon as Cypress type the password it automatically submits a form so `cy.get('#userloginForm form').submit();` is executing after Cypress visits the home page (default redirect) and fail to find a form.

What's wrong? Why does Cypress auto-submit a form after a second time? This is not what Wikipedia is doing since the login form doesn't have any JavaScript code and you need to click login to be able to login to Wikipedia.

**EDIT**:

I've tried to

- Use BaseURL and remove overwrite of `visit`.
- Add `type('{enter}')`, but this only shows an error: `cy.type() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.`

**EDIT 2**

This is the screenshot of the action taken by cypress, second test has a page load without `{enter}` action and without form submit.

[image]

Comment: Why did this get closed after a year? This is not a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit')`.

You pass the parameter with a leading slash `'/wiki/Dyskusja_wikipedysty:<username>'` but concatinate to base which also has a trailing slash `https://pl.wikipedia.org/${path}`, so now the full path is

```js
https://pl.wikipedia.org//wiki/Dyskusja_wikipedysty:<username>
```

If you set `baseUrl` in configuration, Cypress sorts it out for you

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://pl.wikipedia.org'
  }
})
```

Then remove the `Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit')`.

With these changes, I was able to pass both tests.

---

#### Using cy.session()

The problem might be one specific to locality, I do not have any steps missing in the Cypress log.

You can try adding a session cache so that the first login is re-used.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (pass) => {
  cy.session('login', () => {                     // login occurs only once
                                                  // credentials are cached
    cy.visit('/w/index.php?title=Specjalna:Zaloguj');
    cy.get('#wpName1').type('Jack Bosko');
    cy.get('#wpPassword1').type(pass);
    cy.get('#userloginForm form').submit();

    // for good measure, confirm login was successful
    // by checking for your name on the page
    cy.contains('span', 'Jack Bosko')

  })
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work got the same error.

Comment: I just tested it without a problem.

Comment: Am trying to figure out what you mean by " as Cypress type the password it automatically submits a form " - the beforeEach() runs for both tests, and the login command has `cy.get('#userloginForm form').submit()` so it's you code that submits the form. Even so, the tests still pass.

Comment: But it doesn't for me. What is exactly that you're testing that works?

Comment: I run what you have above, but without `cy.matchImageSnapshot()` as your problem is about the login (and the snapshot is a complicating detail that I don't need to set up).

Comment: This "detached from DOM" error - did you have that before? I don't get that issue either. You seem to have a cascade of problems caused by something not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I've created a screenshot, I have the same error without a snapshot. And I'm using Cypress 10 because ImageSnapshot has hardcoded that version in dependencies.

Comment: Would also like to see the error from failing test #2.

Comment: It's in the question `cy.type() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.` it loads the page without submitting so it can't find the DOM element when using `type('{enter}')` got a different error when doing submit on the form.

Comment: That looks like a side-effect of the main problem (whatever that may be). In my 2nd test I get the form submission log followed by `(new url)https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CentralLogin/complete?token=xxxx`.

Comment: Also, I've noticed that the second login has something weird on Wikipedia. Some kind of IME keyboard icon. I've also asked on Cypress repo discussion and on MediaWiki support page. I hope that someone will tell me what it is. Also it works in Firefox but fail on Chrome where that weird keyboard is present after the second login. But in Firefox my submission form was blocked by security.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was the weird IME keyboard that is part of MediaWiki. I somehow got it enabled on my system even when I was not logged in. Maybe added globally with cookies or something.

I noticed that keyboard when I was asking questions on the MediaWiki support page.

This is not related to Cypress. I'm investigating why the keyboard is there, and why clean environment it.